# Constructing PeriodIndex from two int64 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The docs on [`pandas.PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) give the following example for construction:

> `>>> idx = PeriodIndex(year=year_arr, quarter=q_arr)`

And specify the types for those two parameters:

> **year** : int, array, or Series, default None
>
> **month** : int, array, or Series, default None

But I'm running into a TypeError trying to use this type of construction.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# (Year, Month) MultiIndex'd DataFrame
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([2017, 2016], range(1, 13)))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(24, 2), index=idx, columns=['a', 'b'])

print(df.head())
               a         b
2017 1  0.406534 -0.516329
     2 -0.687286 -0.066606
     3  1.493217  0.539294
     4  2.069313  0.415216
     5 -0.212414 -1.375707

# Seems to mimic the construction example from the docs above:
pd.PeriodIndex(year=df.index.get_level_values(0),
               month=df.index.get_level_values(1))
# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

# Same issue even if I specify inputs as NumPy arrays or lists
pd.PeriodIndex(year=df.index.get_level_values(0).values,
               month=df.index.get_level_values(1).values)
pd.PeriodIndex(year=df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist(),
               month=df.index.get_level_values(1).tolist())
```

Bonus question: can I unpack the levels of a MultiIndex?  Presently I have

```
year, month = list(zip(*df.index.get_values()))
```

Is there a prescribed method to get an iterable from the index's levels?

Working in: pandas 0.20.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work by explicitly specifying the frequency string and passing in lists/tuples:

```
In [10]: pd.PeriodIndex(year=df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist(),
    ...:                month=df.index.get_level_values(1).tolist(), freq='M')
    ...:
Out[10]:
PeriodIndex(['2017-01', '2017-02', '2017-03', '2017-04', '2017-05', '2017-06',
             '2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12',
             '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04', '2016-05', '2016-06',
             '2016-07', '2016-08', '2016-09', '2016-10', '2016-11', '2016-12'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Or alternatively unpacking with `zip`:

```
In [11]: pd.PeriodIndex(year,month=zip(*df.index.get_values()), freq='M')
Out[11]:
PeriodIndex(['2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01',
             '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01',
             '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01',
             '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Not sure why it isn't working with an `Index` or numpy array.  Probably a bug.

Comment: Probably a bug yeah - PeriodIndex seems to have a number of issues IMHO.

Comment: @miradulo Yeah, I faced the same issue before ...https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7701